# requesting nasdaq.com in python and nodejs

Tags: python, node.js, node-request

I have encountered the following problem with a get request for nasdaq.com.

I would like to scrape some data with nodejs, but even after hours of trying varous configs all im getting is a 'ECONNRESET'.
With python on the other hand, it works like a charm. 
For now, I have written a workaround fetching the data from node with python-shell and python.

```
const request = require('request')

const options = {
    url: 'https://www.nasdaq.com/',
    headers: {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11',
        'Accept-Encoding': '',
        'Allow': '/'
    },
}

request(options, (err, res, body) => {
    console.log(err)
    console.log(res.statusCode)
})
```

results in

```
{ Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:660:25) errno: 'ECONNRESET', code: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }
```

and

```
from requests import get, Response

res: Response = get('https://www.nasdaq.com/')

print(res.status_code)
```

results in

`200`

This occurs only when requesting nasdaq.com. For all other websites the node get works as expected.

What am I doing wrong with the node request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `superagent` module. It works for me.

```
const request = require('superagent')

request.get('www.nasdaq.com', (err, res, body) => {
   console.log(err)
   console.log(res.statusCode)
});
```